# How to call a parent constructor from a child constructor in C#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, parent

I am trying to call my Person class constructor from my Resident class

Person:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String telephone;
    private String faxNumber;

    Person(String aName, String aSurname, String aAddress1, String aAddress2, String aTelephone, String aFaxNumber)
    {
        name = aName;
        surname = aSurname;
        address1 = aAddress1;
        address2 = aAddress2;
        telephone = aTelephone;
        faxNumber = aFaxNumber;
    }
```

Resident:

```
public class Resident : Person
{
    private String IDNumberPrim;
    private String IDNumberSec1;
    private String IDNumberSec2;
    private String IDNumberSec3;
    private String IDNumberSec4;
    private String tempID;
    private String passportNumber;


    Resident(String aIDNumberPrim, String aIDNumberSec1, String aIDNumberSec2, String aIDNumberSec3, String aIDNumberSec4, String aTempId, String aPassportNumber)
```

I have tried the base command, but it never works.

Please help!!!

------------UPDATE----------------

Problem solved.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What does it say?

Comment: In addition to answering the question about what happens when it doesn't work, please show the code in which you tried `base` unsuccessfully, so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `public` keyword for the constructor, if you want it's access to be public:

```
public Person(String aName, String aSurname, String aAddress1,
              String aAddress2, String aTelephone, String aFaxNumber)
{
    ...
}
```

You could also use `internal` if they are on the same project, or `protected`, since one is a base of the other, etc, but it all depends on what you really want to access modifier for the ctor to be.

The default access modifier is `private`, which does not allow anything from outside that class access that.

Answer (score 8):

Currently your constructors are both defaulting to `private` because you have not included an [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If the `Person` constructor is private and the `Resident` class is separate (ie, not nested in `Person` as Jon Skeet explains), even if it is inheriting from it, it will not have visibility of the constructor.

Simply add a modifier to them, something like `public`, `protected` or `internal`:

```
protected Person(
```

Then you can call into `base` as normal:

```
public Resident() 
    : base() 
{
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have now editted the code as you suggested, but now everyone of the parameters in base() is giving the error message: "The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context." Where xxx is substituted for appropriate parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried the base command, but it never works.

It's not really a "command", but it definitely works:

```
Resident(String aIDNumberPrim, String aIDNumberSec1,String aIDNumberSec2,
         String aIDNumberSec3, String aIDNumberSec4, String aTempId,
         String aPassportNumber)
    : base(...)
{
}
```

Admittedly it's not clear what you'd pass in here, given that none of your parameters appear to indicate a name or address etc... perhaps you need to add more parameters?

EDIT: Also as noted by Adam, you'll need to increase the visibility of your `Person` constructor, unless `Resident` is declared as a nested type within `Person`. It's okay for the `Resident` constructor to stay private if you only need to call it within the program text of `Resident`, but it's more likely that you'll want to increase its visibility too.

(As a side-note, those parameter names are horrible - why prefix everything with `a`?)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that should work:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String telephone;
    private String faxNumber;

    public Person(String aName, String aSurname, String aAddress1, String aAddress2, String aTelephone, String aFaxNumber)
    {
        name = aName;
        surname = aSurname;
        address1 = aAddress1;
        address2 = aAddress2;
        telephone = aTelephone;
        faxNumber = aFaxNumber;
    }

public class Resident : Person
{
    private String IDNumberPrim;
    private String IDNumberSec1;
    private String IDNumberSec2;
    private String IDNumberSec3;
    private String IDNumberSec4;
    private String tempID;
    private String passportNumber;


    Resident(String aIDNumberPrim, String aIDNumberSec1, String aIDNumberSec2, String aIDNumberSec3, String aIDNumberSec4, String aTempId, String aPassportNumber) : base(...)
```

Kind regards, pro

Answer (score 0):

After your the closing parenthesis in Resident's constructor's param list, try saying ': Person(...)' before the braces, supplying the appropriate params in '...':

```c
Resident(String aName, String aSurname, String aAddress1, String aAddress2, String aTelephone, String aFaxNumber,
    String aIDNumberPrim, String aIDNumberSec1, String aIDNumberSec2, String aIDNumberSec3, String aIDNumberSec4, String aTempId, String aPassportNumber) 
: Person (aName, aSurname, aAddress1, aAddress2, aTelephone, aFaxNumber)
{

}
```